# iOS how to implement superscript in a string using escape sequence(\n,\t,\r)

Tags: ios, swift, string, superscript

As far as I can see , I'm sure the super script can be easily done using attributed String but I want to do this with string only

Is there any escape string or some other way to do that ? so that I can make any character or number or symbol to be superscript

Kindly advise

Comment: You've been told the answer, now it's time to move on.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this well is with an attributed text string, applying a smaller font and a baseline offset to the range of the superscript text.

If you want to be able input plain text with escaping for superscript you would need to write a string extension that detects the presence of an "escaping" character, the obvious one being `^`, and generates the formatting for you.  The caveat to this approach is that you either need to know which specific strings need this, or you have to apply it to all strings which will mean that you can't use the "escaping" character in normal text.

There are many example extensions easily found with a quick google, or write your own.

If all you want to do is have numbers in superscript (or subscript) there are a set of unicode characters for this that you can put directly into your text.  It won't look brilliant, but it might be enough.

EDIT: Added example String extension below.

The following will take a plain text string and return an attributed string with superscripting, putting any text surrounded by the delimiter as superscript.  It's basic and hasn't paid any attention to edge cases (eg. using a double delimiter to allow use of the delimiting character in the text) but gives an example that can be built on.

```
extension String {
   func superscripted(delimitedBy marker: Character) -> NSAttributedString {
      
      let superOffset = 10.0
      let superFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6)
      let superAttribs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.baselineOffset: superOffset, .font: superFont]
      
      let attribString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
      var superString = ""
      
      for char in self {
         switch (char, superString.isEmpty){
            case (marker, true): superString.append(char)
            case (marker, false):
               attribString.append(NSAttributedString(string: superString, attributes: superAttribs))
               superString = ""
            case (_, true): attribString.append(NSAttributedString(string: String(char)))
            case (_, false): superString.append(char)
         }
      }
      return attribString
   }
}
```

With this you can use

```
"sdsdfsf^123123^svsvsv^3343^".superscripted(delimitedBy: "^")
```

to get the numeric parts as superscript.

Comment: I can find string extension for attributed string(Superscript) but not for string

Comment: Is there any escaping character for superscript like \n for new line \t for tab and \r for carriage return ?

Comment: @Amogam there's no readily accepted escaping character for superscripting that I'm aware of.  I've added an example String extension for parsing and returning superscripted attributed strings.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use attributed strings but anyways now we know what's possible and what's not. I heard we can use unicode symbols directly on string and it'll give the superscript such as for tm super script we can use \u{2122} but the super script text could be changing. So is it possible we can define some static unicode strings and use it as superscript runtime